Snap positioning for cells in SwiftUI Horizontal ScrollView
I have a horizontal scroll with some fixed size content cells, how can I make it so that it's a swipe to go to the next/previous cell? Similar to a tinder swipe but all remain in the scroll view. I want the cells to 'click' to the leading edge of the Hstack
struct ContentView: View {
        let content = ["Hello", "World", "How", "Are", "You"]
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(content) { str in
                        Text(str)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.green)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


Try applying .scrollTargetLayout() to the HStack and .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging) to the ScrollView. Also:

The ForEach had an error, using .enumerated() is a way to fix this.
Use .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal) to set the width of each view to the width of the containing ScrollView.
It works best when the HStack has spacing: 0. So if you would like spacing between the pages, use padding to achieve it.
The id of the selected page can be tracked by using a .scrollPosition modifier.
An .onChange handler can be used to detect a change of page id. This is where you could trigger an impact effect (ref. your question in a comment).

@State private var pageId: Int?

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Array(content.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, str in
                Text(str)
                    .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(.green)
                    )
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
    .scrollPosition(id: $pageId)
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    .onChange(of: pageId) { oldVal, newVal in
        if let newVal {
            print("page \(newVal) selected")
        }
    }
}



Is there a way to make it work with spacing? And also adding an impact occurred on swipe?

@tHatpart Yes, you can use padding to achieve spacing. An impact effect could be triggered when a change of page is detected, answer updated to show how.

Is it possible to get this effect on iOS 14?

@CacoCavalcanti This particular solution cannot be adapted to iOS 14, it uses a number of functions that are not introduced until later. If you need it to work on iOS 14 then it sounds like you're looking for a completely new solution. It might be possible to get it working using a similar HStack, but you'd need to set the width of the child views to the screen width explicitly and use a DragGesture for handling swipe actions. Alternatively, perhaps consider using a paged TabView?

I need to implement something similar to the sliding rail in the Apple Music app, where an item is highlighted in the center but parts of the items on the sides are also visible. I tried using PageView, but I couldn't achieve this result with the edges of the side items appearing.

@CacoCavalcanti If you're having difficulty getting something to work then you could always create a new post. Be sure to show how far you got.

You are right with the spacing = 0 in the HStack. That solved the issue. Looks like an iOS bug.

@FredericAdda Pleased to hear you found a solution. Ps, you are welcome to upvote the answer if it helped ;)
